# IFNA Vlookup #REF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have the following formula.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C$6,Bullet!AB:AC,1+F5,FALSE),0)
```

To explain; C6 is a postcode field, F5 is a number of pallets field.

In the "Bullet" sheet I have a table of the postcodes and individual pallet delivery prices. I want my formula to find the individual pallet price of the postal area (C6) and then multiply it by the number of pallets (F5).

The formula keeps throwing up #Ref.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you can show us the screenshot or at least dummy data so we can help you with other possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 columns in Bullet!AB:AC so any value in F5 over 1 will kill this with a #REF! error. Expand the range to 1 more than the maximum you expect in F5.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C$6, Bullet!AB:AZ, 1+F5, FALSE), 0)
```

If I understand your narrative, this may be closer to what you want.

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C$6, Bullet!AB:AC, 2, FALSE)*F5, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem is that this could go up to about 50+ pallets it depends on the order.

Comment: I also have another table after this in AD:AE, this is the same principle but for a different delivery company so different prices.

Comment: So expand it further, maybe AB:CB. You go as high as column XFD.

Comment: OK, here are the basics: vlookup takes C6 and tries to find it in the first column of Bullet!AB:AZ, in other words within Bullet!AB. If it finds C6 in column AB, it returns the value from the column indicated by 1+F5. If F5 is 10 then it is tring to return the value from the 11th column within Bullet!AB:AZ so there better be at least 11 columns in that range.

Comment: ah okay so I have the +1 which I don't need. So I put BB into C6 and it will look for BB from AB, the delivery price for this in the bullet table is £31 per pallet which is in column AC. So the number in F5 is the number of pallets so if I have 10 in there I would need to get 10*£31.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify "BB" is a postal code not cell reference.

Comment: I literally just tried that but put the *F5 on the wrong side of 0.